# InvalidArgument=Value of'3' is not valid for 'index'. parameter name: index

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this error in my code: 
InvalidArgument=Value of'3' is not valid for 'index'. parameter name: index ,
 when i want to fill just part of row of my listview !
this is my code:

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select acc_Id,acc_Name,acc_Place from accounts where archived=0 and  cus_Sup=" + 0 , objConn);
                    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (i % 2 == 0)
                            listView2.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString()).BackColor = Color.Lavender;
                        else
                            listView2.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());

                        listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.GetString(1).ToString());

                        listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add((dataReader.IsDBNull(2) ? "No place added" : dataReader.GetString(2)));
                        //------------------------------------I meant here !
                        listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add("0");
                        listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add("0");
                        listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add("0");

                    }
                    dataReader.Close();


                    //-------------load bills
                    for (int x = 0; x < listView2.Items.Count; x++)
                    {
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand("select c.acc_Id,a.bill_Number,a.bill_Date,c.acc_Name,Sum( (b.de_Quantity * b.de_Price) - ((b.de_Quantity * b.de_Price)*b.de_DisRate/100) ),a.bill_TaxRate,a.bill_DisRate,a.bill_Note,c.acc_Place from (accounts c right JOIN bills a on c.acc_Id = a.bill_From) LEFT JOIN  bill_Details b on a.bill_Id = b.bill_Id where c.acc_Id = " + listView2.Items[x].SubItems[0].Text + " group by a.bill_Id,a.bill_Number,a.bill_Date,c.acc_Name,a.bill_TaxRate,a.bill_DisRate,a.bill_Note,c.acc_Place ", objConn);
                        dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        decimal totalSum = 0, summBills = 0;
                        i = 0;
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {

                            totalSum = decimal.Parse(dataReader.IsDBNull(4) ? "0" : dataReader.GetDecimal(4).ToString("n2"));
                            totalSum -= (totalSum * decimal.Parse(dataReader.IsDBNull(6) ? "0" : dataReader.GetDecimal(6).ToString("n2")) / 100);
                            totalSum += (totalSum * decimal.Parse(dataReader.IsDBNull(5) ? "0" : dataReader.GetDecimal(5).ToString("n2")) / 100);
                            summBills += totalSum;
                            i++;
                        }
                        //MessageBox.Show(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString()+"   "+summBills.ToString());
                        listView2.Items[x].SubItems[3].Text = summBills.ToString("n2");// the error here !

                        dataReader.Close();

                    }
```

it's print the value of first record just ! , when it move to the second the error appear !

Answer (score 1):

You've added 3 sub-items to each ListView Item. They will be Items[x].SubItems[0] to SubItems[2]. You would need to have added 4 SubItems to be able to use SubItem[3].

Edit:

When you're adding items in the top loop, you're not incrementing i - you need to change the top loop to:

```
            int i = 0;
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    listView2.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString()).BackColor = Color.Lavender;
                else
                    listView2.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());

                listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.GetString(1).ToString());

                listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add((dataReader.IsDBNull(2) ? "No place added" : dataReader.GetString(2)));
                //------------------------------------I meant here !
                listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add("0");
                listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add("0");
                listView2.Items[i].SubItems.Add("0");

                i++;
            }
            dataReader.Close();
```

Without that, you're adding a new Item to the ListView each time through, but the SubItems are being added every time to listView2.Items[0]. Which is why is fails on the second one. The Items[0] has some multiple of 5 subitems, and the rest have none.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by 'before'. With only 3 SubItems added this: listView2.Items[x].SubItems[3].Text = summBills.ToString("n2"); will always fail at runtime. Either add a 4th SubItem or change it to  listView2.Items[x].SubItems[2].Text = summBills.ToString("n2");

Comment: check the editing ! , i added note where i have been add the subitems !

Comment: Sorry - is //-----I meant here! the line the error is on? Or is it where I see now you're adding extra sub items?